# Cancelling in App purchase in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am in the process of testing my in App purchase in the sandbox environment. When I start the process of "restoreCompletedTransactions" I get the dialogue that asks me to enter the password of the test user. If at that stage I simply press cancel I dont get any feedback that the process has been cancelled.

Any suggestions

Reza

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you cancel restoring purchases `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:` method should get called in your payment transactions observer.

Comment: That seems to work thanks. I was expecting the response to come down to **"paymentQueue: updatedTransactions:"** but it does not.

Comment: @reza23, from docs it looks like "normal" transactions and "restored" transactions have their own different sets of delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

If the user clicks the cancel button then request will fail -  use a store observer like so...

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```

And handle like this....

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, looks like I didn't read carefully what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When the user press the cancel button This Methods are called so place place proper message.

```
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
      }
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
     {
    NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
      }


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue   *)queuerestoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
       NSLog(@"%s","User Cancel.");
      }
```